# How to Remove All Specific Properties in a Model

Tags: python, objects, properties

I have a 3d model with armor and thanks to an addon, my model has become full of custom properties that are bothering me a lot.
I wanted to know how to remove all custom properties that contain the same name without removing the others[image]

I've tried to do the steps of these three questions but nothing helped, always I removed all properties and that I don't want, I wanted to remove only the property that has the name I want to remove
[Remove all custom properties from bones](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/276202/remove-all-custom-properties-from-bones)
[How do I remove ALL custom properties in the entire scene from all objects?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/265324/how-do-i-remove-all-custom-properties-in-the-entire-scene-from-all-objects)

I did exactly what was shown but an error happens and sometimes it deletes all properties instead of removing the one I want. Remembering that I want to remove the properties of the bones and not the model itself

[image]
[image]

Comment: See edit at the end of my answer https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/265327/86891

Comment: Hello, Megui, it seems very likely @Gorgious has answered this with an edit to his answer, so fair to call this a duplicate. If for any reason that doesn't work for you, edit to explain why, and we can re-open for you, pronto.

Comment: I did exactly what was said in the comment, however it gives an error. Remembering that what was taught in the other post is to remove all properties from the Scene, which I don't want, I want to remove Properties from the bones
https://imgur.com/v7OiPzn
https://imgur.com/BuOjPIQ